# Push Notification on Amazon Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, notifications, push

How to implement the Push Notifications in Android for Amazon. I want to upload my app on Amazon store and want to give support for Push Notification as i did with GCM in Google play store.

Answer (score 6):

Since GCM doesn't work on Kindle Fire devices, Amazon has written the Amazon Device Messaging (ADM) API. You can learn more about that here: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm.html

Also, Amazon Web Services has a service (free for low volume use) that lets you write to one server-side API and message out to the different clients on iOS and Android. http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Device messaging library (ADM), is supported only in Kindle devices, except for Kindle Fire 1st generation.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/device-messaging/tech-docs/01-understanding-adm